# Placeholder arguments for curry function in Racket?

Tags: syntax, racket, currying

I'm trying to do something like this while sticking to the core standard library.

```
(define (fn m x b) (+ b (* m x)))

((curry fn _ 3 _ ) 2 4) -> (fn 2 3 4)
```

Is there something like this, or does the Racket community prescribe a different idiom, such as named arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a standard solution, but not in the core library. Simply use the `cut` macro from [SRFI 26](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-26.html):

```
(require srfi/26)

(define (fn m x b)
  (+ b (* m x)))

((cut fn <> 3 <>) 2 4)
=> 10
(fn 2 3 4)
=> 10
```

Comment: One could argue that SRFI libs _are_ part of the core library - they're pretty standard after all, and available in most interpreters.

Comment: It's a part of the included libraries and is not likely it's going to change, but the specification is from Scheme SRFI so this is a part where `lang #racket` follows a standard.